# Why class's static function with generic paradigm(<T extends Parent>) could not use <T extends Child> in subclass

Tags: typescript

the code like:

```
class A { 
    static foo<T extends A>() {
        return {} as T;
    }
}
class B extends A { 
    bar!:number
    static foo<T extends B>() {
        return {} as T;
    }
}
```

the code link is there: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oFgBQ0PQgFzNglsNAGYD2pAPACrQCmAHtrQHYAmMsAfABQCUiaTEOgAnWtgCuI5ogC+0SNCoBuQZlloNqUJBgAhOoxbs4iFOkwAjMCICEALmYSAtpdoi1GHHkIly1QyY2fR5+BE9hMUlpOQUYFQitWSA

the error is:

```
Class static side 'typeof B' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof A'.
  Types of property 'foo' are incompatible.
    Type '<T extends B>() => T' is not assignable to type '<T extends A>() => T'.
      Type 'B' is not assignable to type 'T'.
        'B' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'A'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better or worse, TypeScript enforces that [the static side of a subclass should be compatible with the static side of its superclass](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4628).  Meaning that you should be able to [substitute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) a superclass's static property/method with the same-named property/method from a subclass without error. (Well, except for constructor signatures, which are intentionally exempted from this rule to allow subclass constructors to take different arguments from their superclasses).
It's not clear that this is desirable to everyone (see [relevant comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4628)) but that's the way it is.

Anyway, that means if you have the following code,

```
// some subtype of A that does not extend B
class C extends A {
    baz = 123;
}

let aFoo = A.foo;
aFoo<C>().baz; // number, okay
```

you must be able to substitute `A.foo` with `B.foo` and have it still work:

```
let aFoo = B.foo;
aFoo<C>().baz; // error! C does not extend B
```

But it doesn't.  Your `B.foo()` definition doesn't allow a type parameter of type `C` because `C` does not extend `B`.  Thus `B.foo` cannot be used in place of `A.foo`, and thus `B` does not properly extend `A`.  And that's why you get an error.

---

Not sure what the best way to proceed for you is here.  If this were an instance method instead of a static method, I'd suggest you use [polymorphic `this` types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) to represent the "current" class.  But there are [no such types available to static methods](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5863), so that's not an option.

A possible workaround is to explicitly widen the static side of the class and extend that instead, via a helper function that does very little at runtime:

```
function OmitStatic<T extends new (...args: any) => any, K extends keyof T>(
    ctor: T, ...k: K[]
): Omit<T, K> & (new (...args: ConstructorParameters<T>) => InstanceType<T>) {
    return ctor;
}
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
class A {
    static foo<T extends A>() {
        return {} as T;
    }
}

// note how we extend OmitStatic(A, "foo") instead of A
class B extends OmitStatic(A, "foo") {
    bar!: number
    static foo<T extends B>() {
        return {} as T;
    }
}
```

We still have instance side compatibility:

```
let b = new B();
let a = new A();
a = b; // okay, instance side is still substitutable
```

While the static side behaves as you want without any errors inside the definition of `B`:

```
class C extends A {
    baz = 123;
}
A.foo<C>(); // okay
B.foo<C>(); // not okay
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=64&ssc=1&pln=33&pc=1#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-NteUELhKIxOIJFuj+VpISiJW2jy5WeFNslKYy6WD2mj-Oum6uAO9AtF+fhDi23S7MMYwbg4CJIEEuyJsyqigRhIDYWqjB4Q4hH9EEhIPJ8PxvOgwDVsAIJQOgMjIOg9BQrg+BQBCUIGBwQTrFMEwMGi5y5FR7xfL8EyouOOIqFJwB0tJPwiWyQA)